# How to implement Google Oauth AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oauth-2.0

I'm working on a project and i want to implement the Google and Facebook login button. First thing i done is to go to the official guide and test this simple code and it's work.

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
    <script>
      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
        console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
        console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now i want to connect data received with my database and since i got data with javascript so i send it with AJAX to a generic function with PHP that takes 3 parameters (email, password, method). At method i expect one of these three values ("GOOGLE", "FACEBOOK", "FORM") to know what kind of connection it was. With "GOOGLE" i send id_token instead of password.

```js
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  var posting = $.post(
    "ajax.php",
    {
      "AjaxPostQuery": "Connect", 
      "ConnLogin": profile.getEmail(), 
      "ConnPWD": googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token,
      "method" : "GOOGLE"
    }
  );
  posting.done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $("#connectBox").empty().append(data);
    if(data === ""){
      $("#connectBox").empty().append("You are connected");
      location.reload();
    }
  });
}
```

**The questions**

1. Should i re-implement the Oauth protocol with php to verify if email and id_token are correct or not ?
2. Can i simply trust data received with AJAX (in this case anyone can resend data with console)
3. Am i just an idiot and i skipped something?
4. There is a specific data to store at the database and just compare it?